# How can I convert .append to .concat pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data entry:

```
[{'id': 2269396, 'from': 1647086100, 'at': 1647086160000000000, 'to': 1647086160, 'open': 1.072652, 'close': 1.072691, 'min': 1.072641, 'max': 1.072701, 'volume': 0},..]
```

Apllying this indexing pandas:

```
current = self.getAllCandles(self.active_id,start_candle)
main = pd.DataFrame()
useful_frame = pd.DataFrame()

    for candle in current:
        useful_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(candle.values()),index = list(candle.keys())).T.drop(columns = ['at'])
        useful_frame = useful_frame.set_index(useful_frame['from']).drop(columns = ['id'])
        main = main.append(useful_frame)
        main.drop_duplicates()
    
    final_data = main.drop(columns = {'to'})
    final_data = final_data.loc[~final_data.index.duplicated(keep = 'first')]
     
return final_data
```

After that I have the following result:

```
                  from            open       close        min         max     volume
from                        
1.647086e+09    1.647086e+09    1.072652    1.072691    1.072641    1.072701    0.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Since df.append() will be deprecated, I'm struggling to execute the same instructions using df.concat(). But I'm not getting it, how could I change that?

- Thank you all, I made a small modification to the code suggested by our friend Stuart Berg @stuart-berg, and it was perfect:

```py
    current = self.getAllCandles(self.active_id, start_candle)
    frames = []
            
    useful_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(current, orient='columns')
    useful_frame = useful_frame.set_index('from')
    useful_frame = useful_frame.drop(columns=['at', 'id'])
    frames.append(useful_frame)
    
    main = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates()
    final_data = main.drop(columns='to')
    final_data = final_data.loc[~final_data.index.duplicated()]
    
    return final_data
```

Comment: Can you make a list of "useful_frame"s and concat them after?

Comment: @SiP I appreciate your answer, but it was my first thought unfortunately didn't work.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
current = self.getAllCandles(self.active_id, start_candle)
frames = []
for candle in current:
    useful_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(candle, orient='columns')
    #useful_frame['from'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(useful_frame['from'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    useful_frame = useful_frame.set_index('from')
    useful_frame = useful_frame.drop(columns=['at', 'id'])
    frames.append(useful_frame)

main = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates()
final_data = main.drop(columns='to')
final_data = final_data.loc[~final_data.index.duplicated()]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it didn't work.. :(

Comment: I went to analyze your context better, and it was perfect, thank you very much man, just a small modification: current = self.getAllCandles(self.active_id, start_candle)
        frames = []
        
        useful_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(current, orient='columns')
        useful_frame = useful_frame.set_index('from')
        useful_frame = useful_frame.drop(columns=['at', 'id'])
        frames.append(useful_frame)

        main = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates()
        final_data = main.drop(columns='to')
        final_data = final_data.loc[~final_data.index.duplicated()]

Comment: Okay, glad you found a solution. Good of you to add some example data to the question. If I’d seen that when I answered, then my solution would have been closer to your exact needs. Glad you were able to adapt it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty python list and then append all the series to the list. Finally call pandas' concat on that list, this will give you that dataframe.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it didn't work.